# Formatting a datagrid based on an SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to format some `datagridview` rows, based on if they appear in an SQL select statement.

Here is my code so far.

I have a function to check if the condition is true.

```
Public Shared Function checkdata(ByVal row As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim da As SqlDataReader

    Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyServices; integrated security=yes")
        Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i JOIN [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i2 on i.cli = i2.cli and i.quantity = i2.quantity and i.unitcost = i2.unitcost and i.totalcost = i2.totalcost and i.[description] = i2.[description] and ((i.FromDate <= i2.ToDate)  and  (i.ToDate >= i2.FromDate)) WHERE i.id<>i2.id "
            conn.Open()

            da = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If da.HasRows Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

And an `IF` statement to check each line.

```
    For intcount = 0 To DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1

        If checkdata(intcount) = True Then
            DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView2.Rows(intcount).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
```

The trouble is all the lines in my DataGridView are ALL turning blue.

Where as if I run the SQL I only get 2 results.

My aim is for the 2 rows that are returned in the SQL statement to be formatted with a fore color of blue on the DataGridView.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what all field are there in your datagrid??

Comment: "CLI, CustomerName, FromDate, ToDate, Quantity, UnitCost, TotalCost, Description, Bill"

Answer (score 2):

Change your checking function to this and try
Public Shared Function checkdata(ByVal row As Integer) As Boolean

```
    Dim da As SqlDataReader

    Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyServices; integrated security=yes")
        Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i JOIN [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i2 on i.cli = i2.cli and i.quantity = i2.quantity and i.unitcost = i2.unitcost and i.totalcost = i2.totalcost and i.[description] = i2.[description] and ((i.FromDate <= i2.ToDate)  and  (i.ToDate >= i2.FromDate)) WHERE i.id<>i2.id "
            conn.Open()

            da = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If da.HasRows Then
            while da.read
     if da!fieldindatabase=datagridview.rows(intcount).columns(yourfield)
         return true
     Else
         Return False
     End If
            end while
         End Using
    End Using

 End Function
```

here give the value you get from database for 'fieldindatabase' and the column of corresponding field in datagrid for 'youfield'.

**Note:**

Unfortunately this code will execute the select query for each row in the datagrid.To prevent this,you can use the query to fill a dattable which can be accessed inside the function ,so that it will execute only once(to improve the performance and reduce delay).